# Read array from IRestResponse request

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Trying to get the data in an array from my `Jobject`

```cs
public PostModel GetOnePost(PostModel postmodel, string token)
        {
            JObject response = context.GetOnePost(postmodel, token);

            PostModel post = new PostModel();
            post.Title = response.SelectToken("title").Value<string>();
            post.Content = response.SelectToken("content").Value<string>();
            post.Urgency = response.SelectToken("urgency").Value<string>();
            post.Slug = response.SelectToken("slug").Value<string>();
            post.Completed = response.SelectToken("completed").Value<bool>();
            return post;
        }
```

I want to get the title from the data array... How do I do this?
this also does not work response.SelectToken("data.title")

```
{{
  "success": true,
  "msg": "Post received",
  "data": {
    "postId": "91207a39-6faa-4372-86dc-c5aa6e9f720c",
    "title": "End me",
    "content": "please",
    "slug": "end-me",
    "urgency": "low",
    "completed": false,
    "createdAt": "2019-04-23T08:26:18.988Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-04-23T08:26:18.988Z",
    "clientClientId": "f379f920-a6f9-45b0-95c8-5f91138fb7a5",
    "tags": []
  }
}}  Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject}
```

Comment: Do you have a question ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir yes how do I do get the array from the object?

Comment: can you post your json structure?

Comment: @AnasAL-zghoul done!

Comment: so you want to get the `tags` as array?

Comment: @AnasAL-zghoul no I wan to get title and content as a string

Comment: @im_Ruben i've updated my answer below, hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the `tags` as JSON Array, you can do the following

```
JObject response = context.GetOnePost(postmodel, token);
JArray array = JArray.Parse(response["data"]["tags"].ToString());
```

To get the `title` and `content` as string you do the following

```
JObject response = context.GetOnePost(postmodel, token);
PostModel post = new PostModel();
post.Title = response["data"]["title"].ToString();
post.Content = response["data"]["content"].ToString();
.
.
.
```